# Gnome robot daily quest in Orgrimmar

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Yesterday, I found a gnome robot in Orgrimmar. I could accept a daily quest from him that was instantly completed with a openable bag as reward. I tried to find the gnome again but he's not there anymore.

Where can I find him again?

Comment: Its important to note that this is a free money quest. The items in the gift he gives contain grey items. The value of which can range. I once had a 200g grey item to sell: http://www.wowhead.com/item=86623#contains

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it was the [Blingtron-4000](http://www.wowhead.com/item=86623/blingtron-4000-gift-package)? A skilled engineer can place him anywhere in the world.

In the Pandarian capital for your faction it is very common to find one of them (since most high level engineers don't need to go to Orgrimmar to visit the auction house because they have access to the engineer-only AH in Pandaria), so I guess that's the best place to look for it.

[It looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnOh6.jpg)